# Linux: append all filenames in path to text file

Tags: linux

I want to add the filenames of all files of a certain type (*.cub) in the path to a text file in the same path. This file will become the batch (.submit) file. That I can run overnight. I also need to adapt the name a bit.

I do not really know how to describe it better, so I'll give an example:

Let's say I have three files: 001.cub, 002.cub & 003.cub
Then the final text file must be:

```
[program] -i 001.cub -o 001.vdb
[program] -i 002.cub -o 002.vdb
[program] -i 003.cub -o 003.vdb
```

It seems a fairly easy operation, but I simply can't get it right.

Also, it really has to become a .submit (or at least some text) file. I cannot run the program immediately.

I hope someone can help!

Comment: So if you have `/my/path/to/somefile.txt`, you want to create a new file containing all files matching `/my/path/to/*.cub`? (formatted for submital as shown) You want to provide the path to the textfile as a parameter and have the script do the rest? Or, do you want to scan for `.txt` files and then create a submit file for each directory containing a `.txt` file under some beginning path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create an empty sh file
2. List the files *.cub and loop through them
3. Store the sequence by splitting on dot [.]
4. echo the required string and append to the sh file of step 1

   ```
    echo -n "" > 'Run.sh'
    for filename in `ls *.cub`
    do
        sequence=`echo $filename | cut -d "." -f1`
        echo "Program -i $filename -o $sequence.vdb" >> Run.sh
    done
   ```

Directly put the stream into the file as below:

```
    for filename in `ls *.cub`
    do
        sequence=`echo $filename | cut -d "." -f1`
        echo "Program -i $filename -o $sequence.vdb" 
    done > Run.sh
```

For everything before the extension to be retained in the variable:

```
    for filename in `ls *.cub`
    do
        sequence=`echo $filename | rev | cut -d "." -f2- | rev`
        echo "Program -i $filename -o $sequence.vdb" 
    done > Run.sh
```

For extracting only the numbers from the filename and use accordingly:

```
    for filename in `ls *.cub`
    do
        sequence=`echo $filename | sed 's/[^0-9]*//g'`
        echo "Program -i $filename -o $sequence.vdb" 
    done > Run.sh
```

Comment: Thank you! Especially the bottom part works like a charm and is very clear!

Comment: Glad about that @Roy :)

Comment: Hmm maybe one more question. A problem arose when I had a filename called PI.g_003.cub, since it then cuts it off after the first period in the sequencer line. Do you know how to fix that?

Comment: Gereon's answer however was already addressing that. Guess he deserves the accept for the same. Are you intending to extract only the number from PI.g_003.cub?

Comment: Have edited the answer for the case where you might need only the numbers to be extracted from the filename and updating them in the submit file.

Answer (score 2):

A simple for loop will do the job:

```
for i in *.cub
   b=$(basename "$i" .cub)
   echo "program -i \"$b.cub\" -o \"$b.vdb\""
done >output.txt
```

Comment: Since the expansion is happening here, it might be cleaner to prevent it in the batch file.  That is: `echo "program -i '$b.cub' -o '$b.vdb'"`

Comment: @Gereon learnt something from your answer :) Upvoted! Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

This oneliner will do what you want:

`ls *.cub | sort | awk '{split($1,x,"."); print "[program] -i "$1" -o "x[1]".vdb "}' > something.sh`

Comment: I like your use of `awk`, but piping the output of `ls` is essentially [**Bash Pitfalls #1**](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29). Now you can use a `find .. -print0 | xargs -0 ...` to eliminate the filename problems.

Comment: You're absolutely right!. Another option using "ls" could be this:
`ls *.cub | sort | awk '{split($0,x,"."); print "[program] -i \""$0"\" -o \""x[1]".vdb\" "}'`
This way you avoid the white spaces or apostrophes problem